# Parsing $ from JSON resp in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, youtube-api, angularjs-service

How do I parse in `$` from JSON HTTP responses in AngularJS?

Trying to grab YouTube search results without JQuery:

```js
$http.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/chocolate?alt=json&orderby=published')
    .success(function (data) {
         $scope.video_list = data;
    })
    .error(function (data) {
         $scope.video_list = data;
});
```

No error response from that one, get an Object when consoling it; but cannot query within it.

```js
$scope.video_list_fun = function () {
    $http.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/chocolate?alt=json&orderby=published').then(function (response) {
          $scope.video_list = response.data;
    });
};
```

Same here, have tried with `,` chained `else` also.

```js
$scope.video_list = (httpGet('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/chocolate?alt=json&orderby=published'
                     )); // HttpGet from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4033310/587021
```

This works, but when I parse it, e.g.: with `JSON.parse`; AngularJS gets rid of all the keys with `$` in them.

---

Should note that I have tried with [their other API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), but wasn't able to get the same results (and can't include their useful args for published date and quality; because it's broken).

Comment: Checking out [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1463), there doesn't appear to be a nice solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a cross domain restriction. See if using [$http.jsonp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#jsonp) will work for you.

Check out the ["Using the Data API with JavaScript"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json) in the YouTube documentation where it states you will need to use `alt=json-in-script` as well as the `callback` parameter.

**So instead of accessing:**

```
$http.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/chocolate?alt=json&orderby=published')
```

**You will access:**

```
 $http.jsonp('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/chocolate?alt=json-in-script&orderby=published&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
```

**Note the differences:**

1. Use `jsonp` instead of `get`
2. Use `alt=json-in-script` instead of `alt=json` (note this may be different based on API docs)
3. Add `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` (note this may be different based on API docs but AngularJS is looking for `JSON_CALLBACK` in the response.

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JWxQ/1/) to see a working version (compare with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkzaG/) based on the original code).

Also check out [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) article for more info on JSONP.

Comment: Hmm, I was trying with `jsonp` before using the `success` promise syntax; didn't try with then or the `JSON_CALLBACK` syntax, so thanks :D

Comment: I have tried both syntaxes (with exact same code; char for char), but neither seem to work for me. I have tried from localhost and on my heroku app.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? I modified the first fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3JWxQ/1/) to show some video titles does it work for you?